# How to configure svn server to ignore some dll files when updating?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

When I do `svn up` in command prompt on my server, it updates all the committed files. But I do not want that. I want only certain files to be updated. How do I configure svn server to exclude certain dll files?

I tried in cmd with,

```
>svn propset svn:ignore "*.dll" .
```

But it still included dll files in svn up.

So any help on how to exclude them?